# How to name a function that convert a list of integer into a list of pair?

Tags: python, list

I have a list, each element represents a size of sets.

```
a = [10, 20, 5] # we have 3 bags of balls, each has 10, 20, 5 balls
```

I want to write a function to convert it into a list of pairs, each pair is a pair of the lower and upper limits of sets.

```
b = [(0, 9), (10, 29), (30, 34)] # if we give a serial number to each ball, then #0 ~ #9 ball will be in bag #1, #10 ~ #29 ball will be in bag #2, and so on.
```

now I've wroted a function called a_to_b:

```
a_to_b(a) => b
```

In this case, what should be the appropriate concept to describe a, b and the function a_to_b?

In another word, what should be the appropriate name for a, b and a_to_b? also, what should I call an element in a or b?

Please excuse my poor English, thank you kindly help very much.

Comment: I would simply call it `MakeBags`, and provide really good comments to explain what it is doing.

Comment: uberSmartAndSexyRangifier(a), some examples of functions in code I've had to hammer out: WhyTheHellDoINeedThis(), INeedANewJob(size_t whoUsesSizeT).  The clarity of the function name is inversely proportional to how much aggravation it had caused me.

Comment: Also, could you just name the function in Chinese (which I assume is your native language)? I suggest you check that out, in case it makes your life simpler.

Comment: @gpv0001 Humorous, that is actually what I want to avoid: names that cannot express the idea of this function, so that I have to stare through the code again to make sure what I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any name which makes some sense will do. In general there's no science to this - just provide appropriately descriptive comments so that others (and you, later) can understand what it does without reading the code.

The only time when there is some science to it is when the function is a well known function. For example, if you have a function which rounds a float down to the nearest lesser value with no fractional part, you should probably call it `floor`. A function which pairs up items should probably be called `zip`, because again, that's the usual name.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion (both in the answer and the comment). I found that I'm too nervous about the details. However, I don't think name it in Chinese would be a good idea -- it's rather confusing. lol

Answer (score 0):

```
In [56]: def ranges(L):
    answer = []
    top = 0
    for num in L:
        answer.append((top, top+num-1)); top += num
    return answer
   ....: 

In [57]: L = [10, 20, 5]

In [58]: ranges(L)
Out[58]: [(0, 9), (10, 29), (30, 34)]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not actually an answer to the question

Comment: I answered both the listed question ("What should I name the function") as well as the question that I thought the OP intended to ask ("How do I do this". I answered this question only because the OP confessed to lower English proficiency). So at worst, I answered the question, and then some; or did I completely misunderstand something?

Comment: Well if you're going to play it like that, this doesn't correspond with the example output in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I just wonder if there is a general term to describe this conversion. I even thought it is so general that there should be such a function in the standard library, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not aware of a term for this type of conversion, though I can imagine it being called discrete-range-fill or similar